# phonegap sqlite plugin error

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have added brodysoft sqlite plugin in my phonegap project. when i try to run this project, i get following error:-

```
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld] The library 'sqlite-native-driver.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld] Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld] lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld] The following libraries were found:
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld]  - lib/arm64-v8a/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld]  - lib/armeabi/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld]  - lib/armeabi-v7a/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld]  - lib/x86/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-16 13:36:24 - HelloWorld]  - lib/x86_64/libsqlc-native-driver.so
```

Not finding the way how to resolve this issue. Can anyone help me in this scenerio?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: I have the same problem, so I'll try to elaborate it.
After following the instruccions in [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) it seems that there are no errors detected by Eclipse, but when I try to run it, it reports that error.

Answer (score 4):

I've got in contact with the author of sqlitePlugin (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) and he told me "*unzip sqlite-native-driver.jar and copy the subdirectories from lib to your project's libs directory.*"

So, I downloaded the zip file from that site (the link is at the top right), then extracted the two files in the folder (src/android/libs) and placed them in the project's libs directory. Then, I refreshed the project.

As the error kept going, he told me to "*Make sure you removed sqlite-native-driver.jar*". I deleted that file from the libs directory, refreshed the project, and... the error dissapeared.

All the credits to the author of **litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage**. Thanks to him.