# The library 'sqlite-native-driver.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to get running an old app with newer plugins and API and i get following errors.

```
[2015-07-23 16:13:54 - DemoPia] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia] The library 'sqlite-native-driver.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia] Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia] lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia] The following libraries were found:
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia]  - lib/arm64-v8a/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia]  - lib/armeabi/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia]  - lib/armeabi-v7a/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia]  - lib/x86/libsqlc-native-driver.so
[2015-07-23 16:13:58 - DemoPia]  - lib/x86_64/libsqlc-native-driver.so
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31451879) link  but i still receive same error. 
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to get the same error then the library sqlite-native-driver.jar is still lurking in your libs directory. As described [phonegap sqlite plugin error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31451879) that you linked to, you have to follow the following steps:

1. Extract the contents of sqlite-native-driver.jar (using jar xf sqlite-native-driver.jar  or jar xvf sqlite-native-driver.jar)
2. Copy the *contents* of the lib directory that was extracted from sqlite-native-driver.jar into the libs directory
3. Make sure you remove sqlite-native-driver.jar from your libs directory, otherwise you will continue to see the same error

Finally, I recommend that you completely clean your project of all build artifacts and uninstall the app on your simulator or device.